# Calling beamertemplate frametitle even for empty frametitle

Tags: beamer, templates

Can I force the latex beamer frametitle template to be called even if the `frametitle` is empty?

So in my case I want the black box with "Frametitle: " to appear not only for frames with frametitle, but on every slide.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%% redefine frametitle template
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg = white, bg = black}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \vskip-3pt
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.6em,wd=\paperwidth,leftskip=0cm,rightskip=0cm]{frametitle}%
    \vspace{-2pt}\par
    \hspace{.4cm}Frametitle: \insertframetitle\strut
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

%% mwe document:
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{Heading}
    beamer template ``frametitle'' is called
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}
    beamer template ``frametitle'' is not called
  \end{frame}  
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a version that patches `beamer` to always invoke the template even if the title is empty:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%% redefine frametitle template
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg = white, bg = black}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \vskip-3pt
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.6em,wd=\paperwidth,leftskip=0cm,rightskip=0cm]{frametitle}%
    \vspace{-2pt}\par
    \hspace{.4cm}Frametitle: \insertframetitle\strut
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

% make beamer always use the frametitle template, even if frametitle is empty
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\endbeamer@frameslide}{\ifx\beamer@frametitle\@empty}{\iffalse}{}{\errmessage{failed to patch}}
\makeatother

%% mwe document:
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{Heading}
    beamer template ``frametitle'' is called
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}{}
    beamer template ``frametitle'' is not called
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can cheat by adding a `\null` or `\mbox{}` or `\phantom{some text}`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%% redefine frametitle template
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg = white, bg = black}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \vskip-3pt
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.6em,wd=\paperwidth,leftskip=0cm,rightskip=0cm]{frametitle}%
    \vspace{-2pt}\par
    \hspace{.4cm}Frametitle: \insertframetitle\strut
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

%% mwe document:
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{Heading}
    beamer template ``frametitle'' is called
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}{\null}
    beamer template ``frametitle'' is not called
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\begin{frame}{{}}` will do it.

Comment: Thank you. The `\begin{frame}{{}}` is the most elegant solution at the moment. Nevertheless, I want to add it to a new beamer theme an it should be done hidden somehow. Maybe I can redefine the frame-environment?

Comment: Another way which keeps other related formatting (for me it is important): `\begin{frame}{\strut}`